# Split unique forward slash

Tags: regex, perl

```
 ./dms:element[@name="obj_id"]/dms:qualifier[@name="object_status"]/@value[obj_id_status]
```

Trying to split the string so that the result comes out as

```
./dms:element[@name="obj_id"]
dms:qualifier[@name="object_status"]
value[obj_id_status]
```

Is there a way to do this with regex? I want to split when `/` is alone, but not split `./` and also remove `/@`.

Comment: That looks like xpath. Are you trying to manually process xpath queries? (If so, why treat `./` differently?)

Comment: `perl -ne 'my @sections = split /\//, $_; foreach (@sections) { s/^@//; print $_; print "/" if m/^\.|\.$/; print "\n" unless m/^\.|\.$/; }' your_input_file` prints your desired output. Sorry for the quick code. It's been done... quickly

Comment: @yonyon100: That also splits on slashes preceded by a dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use v5.10;

my $s = './dms:element[@name="obj_id"]/dms:qualifier[@name="object_status"]/@value[obj_id_status]';

my @parts = split qr|(?<!\.)/\@?|, $s;

say for @parts;
```

#### output

```
./dms:element[@name="obj_id"]
dms:qualifier[@name="object_status"]
value[obj_id_status]
```

Comment: My answer still stands

Comment: This won't remove the `/@`

Comment: Just regex it out afterwards. Simple substitution. `$parts[-1] =~ s{^/@}{}`, or with `map` if it can be in any position.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. So you want to split on slashes that aren't preceded by a dot, and remove the first two characters if the slash is followed by an `@`? That's a weird requirement. Try my modification.

Comment: @Borodin Yup it is a weird requirement. Basically remove `/` and `/@` but keep `./` Thanks for your help. This removes `/@` but not `/`. Hah.

Comment: Your example doesn't remove `/`, only `/@`. Do you want to remove both?

Comment: @Borodin Yes. My example does remove `/` if it's alone and not preceded by `.`

Comment: @Borodin Now it does not remove `/` or `/@`

Comment: Sorry. Try again.

Comment: @Borodin Thank you Genius.